# Bind a function to checkboxes in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I cannot get a jQuery function to execute upon click or change of a checkbox in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1.  I have tried everything I know to try, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the html:

```
<form>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
    <li style="padding:0">
      <a href="#" style="padding:0">
       <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="task-container">
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-1">
         <label for="checkbox-1" style="border: none;margin: 0">Task name</label>
       </fieldset>
      </a>
      <a href="#purchase">Purchase album</a>
    </li>
    .
    .
    .       
   </ul>
</form>
```

And here is the JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$("#checkbox-1").change(function() {
  alert("hello world!");
});
```

Comment: Label and input names are different, they should be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I changed the label and input names so that they match and that does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

One reason might be because you're initializing this before the element already existed. Try wrapping your `change` event in a `pageinit` event if this is in a container with `data-role` set to `page` (which it must have), like this :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "[data-role=page]", function () {
    $("#checkbox-1").change(function () {
        alert("hello world!");
    });
});
```

Your HTML might/must look like this :

```
<div data-role="page" id="mypage">
    <div data-role="content">

     <!-- what you've typed in the question -->

   </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/UNR8v/) :

**Option 2**

One more way to work this out would be to place this change event at the end `<body />` tag (Like this must be the last element in `body`). Change `no wrap in <head>` to `no wrap in <body>` in the fiddle options and see it work out :)

**Option 3**

Try binding the event to the document or the most immediate static parent and delegating it from there :

```
  $(document).on("change", "#checkbox-1", function () {
      alert("hello world!");
  });
```

Comment: My HTML does look like the above, but I tried wrapping my change event in a pageinit event as you recommended but it still does not work unfortunately.  Do you know what else may be causing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the second way I've suggested in the answer? @CoreyQuillen..it would be helpful if you made a fiddle yourself

Comment: To get it working, I used the pageinit event wrapper (Option 3 above) and add a data-role="none" attribute to the checkbox input element.  Apparently, one of the input styling enhancements built into JQM was interfering with the jQuery selector I was using.  Thanks for your help!